# InstantiateViewController calls ViewDidLoad

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a classic master-detail logic and trying to create instance of detail UIViewController with InstantiateViewController inside a click event.

Here is my code,

**MasterViewController.cs**

```
detailButton += delegate {
   UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
   Console.WriteLine("InstantiateViewController() started");
   var profileController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ProfileController") as ProfileController; 
   Console.WriteLine("InstantiateViewController() ended");
   profileController.Id = 5;  
};
```

**ProfileViewController.cs**

```
public partial class ProfileController : UIViewController
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override void ViewDidLoad() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("ViewDidLoad() called");
    }
}
```

When I click the button output is,

```
InstantiateViewController() started
ViewDidLoad() called
InstantiateViewController() ended
```

This means `profileController.Id` is set after `ViewDidLoad()` which means I can't load data by Id in ViewDidload event beacuse Id is null.

So my question is why `ViewDidLoad()` called by InstantiateViewController(), in which method should I load data by Id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VoewDidLoad` is [called](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) when the `ViewController` is loaded into memory.

So, the correct place to get the data is on `ViewDidAppear`.
`ViewDidAppear` notifies the `ViewController` that its view was added to a view hierarchy.

UPDATE:

Based on the new information provided in comments you could do something like this:

```
public partial class ProfileController : UIViewController
{
    private int _id;

    public void SetupProfile (int id)
    {
        // Save the Id if necessary.
        _id = id;
        // Add event with this id related.
    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("ViewDidLoad() called");
    }
}
```

In alternative if you still want to do the event setup in `ViewDidAppear` you could use this approach with the events:

```
yourClass.Event -= MyHandler;
yourClass.Event += MyHandler;
```

Comment: Probably viewWillAppear is better; the load can be started before the view is onscreen. If it is asynchronous then the op still needs to allow for the case where the load is not complete before the view does appear

Comment: ok nice approach, but i will also set click event handlers, I know that  ViewDidAppear will be called everytime view appear on window, so my click events will be created one more time on every call. what about this?

Comment: In this case it wasn't async so I assumed ViewDidAppear was fine.

Comment: Why you can't set your events in ViewDidLoad? I know its called when you InstantiateViewController. But its the place to set the events.

Comment: @jzeferino, in this case events will be created Id based, I just simplify my problem.

Comment: @ocanal so, instead of setting the ID, call a setup method that receive the id and internally add the event. Added sample in answer.

Comment: Normally this would be done via the segue, if you are not using Storyboard-based segue, then using one programmatically will work, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do this via a custom segue.

1) Create a custom segue that can be re-used throughout your app:

```
public class CustomSeque : UIStoryboardSegue // or UIStoryboardPopoverSegue depending upon UI design so you can "POP" controller
{
    public CustomSeque(String identifier, UIViewController source, UIViewController destination) : base (identifier, source, destination) { }

    public override void Perform()
    {
        if (Identifier == "StackOverflow")
        {
            // Are you using a NavigationController?
            if (SourceViewController.NavigationController != null)
                SourceViewController.NavigationController?.PushViewController(DestinationViewController, animated: true);
            else 
                SourceViewController.ShowViewController(DestinationViewController, this);
        } else
            base.Perform();
    }
}
```

2) Then you can:

```
UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
Console.WriteLine("InstantiateViewController() started");
var profileController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ProfileController") as ProfileController;
var seque = new CustomSeque($"StackOverflow", this, profileController);
profileController.Id = 5;
profileController.PrepareForSegue(seque, this); // instead of *this*, you can pass any NSObject that contains data for your controller
seque.Perform();
Console.WriteLine("InstantiateViewController() ended");
```

If your `ProfileController` looks like this:

```
public partial class ProfileController : UIViewController
{

    public ProfileController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        Id = -99;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override bool ShouldPerformSegue(string segueIdentifier, NSObject sender)
    {
        if (segueIdentifier == "StackOverflow")
            return true;
        return base.ShouldPerformSegue(segueIdentifier, sender);
    }

    [Export("prepareForSegue:sender:")]
    public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);
        Console.WriteLine("ProfileController.PrepareForSegue()");
        Console.WriteLine($"  - ID = {Id}");
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        Console.WriteLine("ProfileController.ViewDidLoad()");
        Console.WriteLine($"  - ID = {Id}");
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        Console.WriteLine("ProfileController.ViewWillAppear()");
        Console.WriteLine($"  - ID = {Id}");
    }
}
```

Your sequenced output would be:

```
InstantiateViewController() started
ProfileController.PrepareForSegue()
- ID = 5
ProfileController.ViewDidLoad()
- ID = 5
InstantiateViewController() ended
ProfileController.ViewWillAppear()
- ID = 5
```